# Is there a Windbg command to look inside the High Frequency Heap?

Tags: .net, debugging, clr, windbg, heap-memory

Is there a Windbg/NTSD command that will show us the contents of the high frequency heap?

Comment: Thanks very much. :-)

Comment: Actually, it could be lack of knowledge but I think your question has a few details that do not sit well with my knowledge. The `-min` and `-max` switches of the `dumpheap` take *object sizes* and not *addresses*? Secondly, I said that the `Program` class would not be found on the `gc heap`. The `dumpheap` only shows us the *gc heap*, right? It doesn't dump the contents of the loader heap?

Comment: Yes, if you just provided the START and END addresses like so: `!dumpheap <start> <end>`.

Comment: This guy (http://dotnetdebug.net/2005/07/04/dumpheap-parameters-and-some-general-information-on-sos-help-system/) says it is the `-fix` switch but it works for me without the switch and doesn't with the switch. That is, it shows me the contents within the address range without any switch if I just give the starting and ending addresses.

Comment: @ThomasWeller With your permission, if you won't feel bad, could I remove the extra information you have added to the original question because it doesn't support the question? The question was clear. It is now mixed with all kinds of messages. For e.g. I am *asking how to see inside the high-frequency-heap* and not doing `!dumpheap <start_of_high_freq_heap> <end_...>` because `dumpheap` only looks inside the *gc heap*. It does not look inside the loader heap, which is a separate thing.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the address of the high frequency heap with the command

```
!eeheap
```

Then you can view the contents of that address with the command

```
!do
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I'd already tried that. The address of the loader heaps do not point to objects.